# How to use the same environment as the one I am using in cron jobs?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron, redhat

I've read a lot of threads on crontab and env, but I still cannot set it right.

I used

```
env > env_setting
```

Because I need to use the same env setting and bash to run, so in `crontab -e`

```
*/1 * * * * env - `cat /path/to/env_setting` /bin/bash ; /bin/bash /path/to/program.sh
```

But it doesn't work. How to use the same environment as the one I am using in cron jobs?

P.S I'm using Red Hat.

Edit:
I tried the following in `program.sh`

```
env >> temp.log 2>&1
env - `cat /path/to/env_setting`
env >> temp.log 2>&1
```

But the 2 `env` outputs in `temp.log` are exactly the same. Didn't employ the `env_setting`

Comment: the `env cat - ... /bin/bash` is one process. The `;` indicates "start a new process" . There is probably a better solution overall, but try `env - 'cat /path/to/env_settings' /bin/bash /path/to/prog.sh`, where the `'` chars are really back-tics, or can't you use "modern" cmd-sub with `$(.cmd-sub...)`? Good luck.

Comment: Actually I had tried your way before I posted the post, but it didn't work.

Comment: so you can't add a line at the top of `./program.sh`  : `. /path/to/env` (source the file in the script?). Good luck.

Comment: Tried. I added detail above. Not working.

Comment: I mean a one time per enviroment, seperate from any script, run `set > env.file` on the cmd-line when you have your env the way you want it ; then add `. /path/to/env.file` at the top of all your scripts. I don't see what benefit you expect from `env >> temp.log 2>&1' etc. But it wouldn't be the first time I missed the point on something ;-) ... Got to go. May not be back until tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: I usually schedule an at job, e.g. `echo pwd | at 'next min' ` which gives a reply like "job 10 at ...." then I get the job with `at -c 10`  and that contains the full environment of the current shell set up in a way to be usable in a script for cron.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` has a number of quirks and problems, and its handling of environment variables is a notable one. You can try to work around the issue by re-importing your environment, but when possible a much better option is to just avoid `cron` entirely. For many use cases the [`at` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) works much better, and among other features runs within *your* environment, rather than `cron`'s stripped down one.

More info:

- [Conveniently schedule a command to run later?](https://askubuntu.com/q/339298)
- [Why do we need the “at” command in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97882/19157)